# importValue function does not work in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I see a very strange issue with cloud formation import value function in cloudformation. I am trying to create a cloudformation beanstalk environment. in the configurationTemplate section I have :

```
 configurationTemplateChannel:
Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
Properties:
  ApplicationName:
  - Fn::ImportValue:
      Fn::Sub: "${StackNamePrefix}-BeanstalkId-test"
  Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Configuration Template
  OptionSettings:
       .
       .
       .         
  - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
    OptionName: VPCId
    Value:
      Fn::ImportValue:
        Fn::Sub: "${StackNamePrefix}-vpc-VpcId"
     .
     .
     .
```

As you see I have  import in   ApplicationName which result in:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: [/Re                    sources/configurationTemplateChannel/Type/OptionSettings/6/Value/0/Fn::ImportVal                    ue] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Does this mean that I cannot use import option here?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The path in the error `sources/configurationTemplateChannel/Type/OptionSettings/6/Value/0/...` doesn't seem to reflect the template in your question. Can you make sure it is ? And could you also update your code snippet with a bit more context, since the error could hide there.

Comment: Hey thanx for answering, this is what  I run in terminal with the right file I think. Now I found the issue when I replace it with  Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${StackNamePrefix}-BeanstalkId-test it works but the question is that what is the difference? why does it work for the second one?

Comment: I really can't explain it since they virtually the same thing. However, I prefer the shorthand `!` versions so moving to this syntax isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Yeah thanx for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further readers: I found the issue when I replace it with Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${StackNamePrefix}-BeanstalkId-test it works